# Spark getting slow as time goes on

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a scala code that runs on top of spark 2.4.0 to compute the BFS of a graph which is stored in a table as below:

| src | dst | isVertex |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... |

At some point in the algorithm, I need to update the visited flag of current vertex neighbors. I am doing this by the following code. When I execute the code, it works fine but as time goes on, it becomes slower and slower. It seems that the last nested loop is the problem:

```
//var vertices = schema(StructType(Seq(StructField("id",IntegerType),StructField("visited", IntegerType),StructField("qOrder",IntegerType))

val neighbours = edges.filter($"src" === start).join(vertices,$"id" === $"dst").filter($"visited" === lit(0))
                .select($"dst".as("id")).withColumn("visited", lit(1)).withColumn("qOrder", lit(priorityCounter)).cache()

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    vertices.collect.foreach{x=> 
                    if(!neighbours.filter(col("id")===x(0)).head(1).isEmpty){
                    vertices = vertices.filter($"id" =!= x(0)).union(neighbours.filter(col("id")===x(0))).cache()
                }
            }
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When it becomes slow, it starts giving the following errors and warnings:

```
2021-06-08 19:55:08,998 [driver-heartbeater] WARN  org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Issue communicating with driver in heartbeater

org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.executor.heartbeatInterval

Exception in thread "dag-scheduler-event-loop" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Does anyone have any idea about the problem?
I have set the spark parameters as follows:

```
spark.scheduler.listenerbus.eventqueue.capacity   100000000
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled  true
spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout  2m
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors  1
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors  10000
spark.max.fetch.failures.per.stage  10
spark.rpc.io.serverThreads  64
spark.rpc.askTimeout 600s
spark.driver.memory              32g
spark.executor.memory           32g
```

Comment: spark version ??

Comment: The spark version is 2.4.0